# Login System VB.net and Access Check if the user is an Admin

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I would like my program to check if a user is an admin. I followed a tutorial on the internet on how to do make a login form, and im super new to programming.[This is my database in access.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeWMc.jpg)

If that box in access is ticked then i would like it to show the "AdminMenu" form to show but if the box isn't ticked i would like it to show the "UserMenu" The code below works fine but like i said i would like to know how i check if that user is an admin or just a normal user

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username and password are blank", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ' Both fields was supply
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
    Else
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\-------.ult.org.uk\homestudent\-------\dt_database.accdb"
        Try
            'conn.Open()
            'MsgBox("Susscess")
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()


            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                AdminMenu.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else

                ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
                ' Throw an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                'Clear all fields
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox2.Text = ""

                'Focus on Username field
                TextBox1.Focus()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DataReader (sqlRead) to check the content of the "admin"-column. Compare it to the state you'd like (-1 is TRUE, 0 is FALSE).

```
if sqlReader.item("admin") = -1 then
        'IsAdmin
else       
        'IsNotAdmin
end if
```

Sidenote: do not concatenate querystrings. It's a bad practice and renders the application prone to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your schema and the `SELECT *`.  You need to read the actual value of your `admin` field.

```
If sqlRead.Read() Then
    If Convert.ToBoolean(sqlRead(6)) = True Then 'By ordinal   OR
    If Convert.ToBoolean(sqlRead("admin")) = True Then 'By field name
        'User Is Admin
    Else
        'User is not admin
    End If
    AdminMenu.Show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
```

Comment: Dries's code works as well, and it looks a lot simpler. Is there some disadvantage of using it?